# Объединение объектов в Java

Tags: java, объекты

Есть ли возможность в Java объединить объекты одного класса разных конструкторов в один объект этого же класса(или другого)?

Comment: конструкторы (независимо от их количества) выполняют 2 задачи: создание экземпляра класса и инициализация переменных. класс описывает абстракцию. класс и объект соотносятся примерно как велосипед и чертеж, где чертеж - класс. чертеж один, но по нему собирают много разных велосипедов. к примеру, если ваш класс описывает человека и вы получили 2 объекта: васю и петю, то как вы представляете их объединение? должен получится васепет ?

Comment: представлялось примерно так , что создав объект вася у которого есть возраст и рост,  прибавить к нему из другого конструктора его вес в тот же объект. Думаю просто как в созданный объект добавить еще данные из этого же класса?

Comment: Если вам нужно изменить объект, который уже загружен в память - меняйте его состояние через методы-сеттеры. Объединить два загруженных в память объекта в один - вообще не понятно что именно вы хотите сделать, но скорей всего - нет.

Comment: давайте еще раз. конструктор - не обычный метод. он создает новый экземпляр класса. если вы из класса, описывающего абстрактного человека, создали васю, то вызов коннструктора приведет к созданию нового объекта, а не изменению объекта вася. хотите изменить возраст васи - напишите обычный метод с соответсвующей логикой (метод, но не конструктор)

Comment: @dmtr менять через сеттеры - очень плохая идея. таким образом вы нарушаете паттерн GRASP information expert. суть в том, что информация должна обрабатываться там, где хранится. а вы предлагаете написать логику изменения поля, описывающего человека, в стороннем объекте и потом сеттером записать результат. такой код в итоге не поддается рефакторингу, абсолютно не расширяем и его невозможно читать. все, что с ним можно сделать, - удалить

Comment: @Дмитрий еще скажите, что в реальном продкшене так не делают, ага. И да, я не предлагал это сделать в стороннем объекте.

Comment: @dmtr не совсем понял первого аргумента. джава - достаточно старый язык. даже 10 лет назад про паттерны мало кто слышал. со временем появляются новые методологии разработки и это нормально. все совершенствуется. но код, который написан на джаве 10 и более лет назад, по прежнему надо поддерживать. а еще есть индусы. а кроме индусов есть огромное количество разработчиков, которые до сих пор про GRASP не слышали. это совсем не означает, что нужно постоянно наступать на одни грабли. И да, я не предлагал это сделать в стороннем объекте. - тогда откуда вы предлагали вызвать сеттер?